# Android how to stop START_STICKY service

Tags: android, service

My app uses a thirdparty library and this library starts a START_STICKY service. So even app is destroyed and service is killed, it automatically restarted.

My question is, is there any way I can change this service lifecycle as same as the app? service is started when app is started, service is stopped when app is stopped.

Answer (score 2):

Add a **intent Filter** to that service in the manifest file

```
 <service
        android:name="ServiceName"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="IntentName"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

then use this intent to start or stop the service any where u want

```
String intentName="IntentName";
Intent i=new Intent(itentName);
context.stopService(i);
```

or

```
context.startService(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options:

- Do you have access to it's service's intent? in that case you can call [stopService(theIntent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent))
- If you can access the service instance you can do [stopSelf()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf())

Comment: Thanks! I tried: Intent intent = new Intent(this, Service.class) in onDestroy. But the service still restarted. How can I access server instance?

Comment: you mean stopService(new Intent(yourContext, TheService.class)) ? In that case I think that the library is starting it again. Can you provide more information about the library?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? if so please write us the result or mark this answer as good, otherwise please provide more information